# How do I write data to an array using checkbox?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

I have this code

```
const [selectedStudents, setSelectedStudents] = useState([])
const studentsChangeHandler = (e) => {
  setSelectedStudents({...selectedStudents,[e.target.id]:e.target.value});
  console.log('selectedStudents is ',selectedStudents)
};
```

and on the website

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  id={index}
  value={student._id}
  onChange={studentsChangeHandler}
/>
```

And when I select the first checkbox on the site, nothing is written, but the second one is written, why?

[image: first]

[image: second]

Comment: Because `setSelectedStudents` is not synchronous. So, the state changes you can see on the next render. That's why in the `console.log` you are seeing the previous state.

Comment: @Nithish so everything works?

Comment: as a result, I get the object this way, can I somehow make it a pure array?  @Nithish

Comment: Yes, everything should work. You can use `useEffect` in order to see the changes.

Comment: The reason why it's storing as object is you are passing an object to `setSelectedStudents` in `studentsChangeHandler`. instead you should add the new id. That's the coding mistake I can say.

Comment: I have provided an answer with the required changes. Please check if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general `setState or useState` in React is asynchronous. So, the updated state we'll not be able to capture in the as soon as we update the state.

In hooks, the updated state will be available in the next render only. So, in order to see if the state is getting updated or not, we can make use of `useEffect` hook. Below is the example for the same.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [students, setStudents] = useState([]);
  
  const onChangeHandler = event => {
    const {target: {id, value}} = event;
    setStudents(prevStudents => {
      //Push the new object with the id as key and value 
      //of the checkbox as value in the array.
      //In your case the value will be the student id. 
      //But here for simplicity I have used 1, 2 as ids & values
      return [...prevStudents, {[id]: value}]
    });
  }
  
  //To print the initial state as well as whenever the state(i.e., students gets updated
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(students);
  }, [students])
  
  return (
   <div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="1" value="1" onChange={onChangeHandler}/>
      <span>Input 1</span>
    </div>
    <div> 
     <input type="checkbox" id="2" value="2" onChange={onChangeHandler}/>
     <span>Input 2</span>
    </div>
   </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

Note: For the demo purpose I have not considered removing the objects from the state when the checkbox is getting unchecked. I'm just adding a new object with `id` as key and value as `value` in the array irrespective of the state of the checkbox. So, please update the `onChangeHandler` logic as per your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jquery. This example selects the checked checkboxes by a selector and then calls the .each() method to each element and finally push them into the array.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
<head>
    <title>
        JQuery | Get all selected checkboxes in an array.
    </title>
    <style>
        #GFG_UP {
            font-size: 17px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
          
        #GFG_DOWN {
            color: green;
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
          
        button {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<script src=
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
  
<body style="text-align:center;" id="body">
    <h1 style="color:green;">  
            Geek
        </h1>
    <p id="GFG_UP">
    </p>
      
    <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="GFG" /> GFG:
    <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="Geeks" /> Geeks:
    <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="Geek" /> Geek:
    <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="portal" /> portal:
    <br>
    <button>
        click here
    </button>
    <p id="GFG_DOWN">
    </p>
    <script>
        $('#GFG_UP')
        .text('First check few elements then click on the button.');
        $('button').on('click', function() {
            var array = [];
            $("input:checkbox[name=type]:checked").each(function() {
                array.push($(this).val());
            });
            $('#GFG_DOWN').text(array);
        });
    </script>
</body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: this will work, but isn't it better to avoid it in React?